# array.push() only contains final value from loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have the following JavaScript (Typescript) sample, where I initialise an Array and then push a timestamp of every hour until the `end` timestamp is included in the range.

```
let res = [start];
while (res[res.length - 1].isBefore(end)) {
    let nextTime = res[res.length - 1].add(1, 'hour'); // add one hour to the previous result - this is a moment.js instance
    console.log('loop', nextTime.format())
    res.push(nextTime);
}
res.forEach(val => console.log('result', val.format()))
```

The `console.log` from the loop logs out the expected values e.g.

> loop 2017-03-27T18:00:00+01:00
>
> loop 2017-03-27T19:00:00+01:00
>
> loop 2017-03-27T20:00:00+01:00

However, the resulting array only seems to contain the correct number of records but they are all the final value, e.g.

> result 2017-03-28T18:00:00+01:00
>
> result 2017-03-28T18:00:00+01:00

Why is this?

Comment: What's `nextTime`, a MomentJS instance?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes, have updated the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MomentJS objects are mutable (changeable) objects with state. Calling `add` on a MomentJS object modifies it, but doesn't create a new object; it just returns a reference to the same object. So say you start with this:

```
     +−−−−−−−−−+        
res−>| (array) |        
     +−−−−−−−−−+        +−−−−−−−−−−+    
     | 0       |−−−−−−−>| (object) |    
     +−−−−−−−−−+        +−−−−−−−−−−+   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+ 
                        | d:       |−−>|                  (Date)                  | 
                        +−−−−−−−−−−+   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+ 
                                       | [[TimeValue]]: 2017−03−27T18:00:00+01:00 |
                                       +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

Your

```
let nextTime = moment(res[res.length - 1]).add(1, 'hour');
// ...
res.push(nextTime);
```

modifies that object and pushes another reference to it onto `res`:

```
     +−−−−−−−−−+        
res−>| (array) |        
     +−−−−−−−−−+        +−−−−−−−−−−+   
     | 0       |−−−−+−−>| (object) |   
     | 1       |−−−/    +−−−−−−−−−−+   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
     +−−−−−−−−−+        | d:       |−−>|                  (Date)                  |
                        +−−−−−−−−−−+   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                                       | [[TimeValue]]: 2017−03−27T19:00:00+01:00 |
                                       +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

Notice how the state of the object (the [[TimeValue]] in the `Date` used by the MomentJS object) has changed.

If you do it again, we just update it again:

```
     +−−−−−−−−−+        
res−>| (array) |        
     +−−−−−−−−−+        +−−−−−−−−−−+   
     | 0       |−−−−+−−>| (object) |   
     | 1       |−−−/    +−−−−−−−−−−+   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
     | 2       |−−/     | d:       |−−>|                  (Date)                  |
     +−−−−−−−−−+        +−−−−−−−−−−+   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                                       | [[TimeValue]]: 2017−03−27T20:00:00+01:00 |
                                       +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

Instead, you want to create a new object. You can do that by cloning the original with [`moment`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/moment-clone/).

```
let nextTime = moment(res[res.length - 1]).add(1, 'hour');
// ------------^^^^^^^   ----------------^
// ...
res.push(nextTime);
```

If you do that, then from the same starting point, we get:

```
     +−−−−−−−−−+        
res−>| (array) |        
     +−−−−−−−−−+        +−−−−−−−−−−+   
     | 0       |−−−−−−−>| (object) |   
     | 1       |−−−−+   +−−−−−−−−−−+   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
     | 2       |−−+ |   | d:       |−−>|                  (Date)                  |
     +−−−−−−−−−+  | |   +−−−−−−−−−−+   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+ 
                  | |                  | [[TimeValue]]: 2017−03−27T18:00:00+01:00 | 
                  | |   +−−−−−−−−−−+   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+ 
                  | +−−>| (object) |                                                
                  |     +−−−−−−−−−−+   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+ 
                  |     | d:       |−−>|                  (Date)                  |
                  |     +−−−−−−−−−−+   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+ 
                  +−−−−>               | [[TimeValue]]: 2017−03−27T19:00:00+01:00 | 
                        +−−−−−−−−−−+   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+ 
                        | (object) |                                                
                        +−−−−−−−−−−+   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+ 
                        | d:       |−−>|                  (Date)                  |
                        +−−−−−−−−−−+   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                                       | [[TimeValue]]: 2017−03−27T20:00:00+01:00 |
                                       +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

Comment: @ArthurCinader can guess the library which OP are using is not too easy, and solve the problem so quickly.